# Unable to cast a object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2 [VB $ AnonymousType_8`9

Tags: vb.net, linq, query-optimization

I have written a query by using the linq to Datatable, but I don't know what is the type to use to declare my variable `queryArchi`? I have tried the type `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of Object)` but I get a message error :

> Unable to cast a object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2 [VB $ AnonymousType_8`9

Code:

```
Dim queryArchi As System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of Object)
Dim queryStructure

If tf = 0 Then
    queryArchi = (From b In DataBien.AsEnumerable()
           Group b By b!code_projet, b!code_operation, b!code_type, b!Designation_part, b!code_part Into Group
           Select code_projet, code_operation, code_type, NBP = Group.Count())
Else
    queryArchi = (From b In DataBien.AsEnumerable()
          Group b By b!code_projet, b!code_operation, b!code_type, b!Designation_part, b!code_part, b!Titré Into Group
          Select code_projet, code_operation, code_type, Titré, NBP = Group.Count())
End If

If vil <> "" Then queryArchi = queryArchi.Where(Function(d) d.code_projet = vil)

queryStructure = queryArchi.ToList
```

Comment: Have you tried `IEnumerable(Of Object)`?  `IEnumerable(Of T)` is covariant in its type argument, so you can assign an enumerable of something derived from `T`.  Since everything descends from `Object`, you should be able to assign any `IEnumerable(Of )` to an `IEnumerable(Of Object)`.

Comment: Don't project (`Select code_projet, ...`) to an anonymous type, but a named type containing properties `code_projet, code_operation, code_type, Titré, Count`, so `queryArchi` can be `IEnumerable(Of NamedType)`